# how to use different closure types in swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I am studying the clussures in swift but i dont really get the difference between these function types and what is the point of these defferences .I do understand the first and the second one somehow but the last one makes me commpletely confused . for example :

```
 func performMagic (thingy : String ){ 
      return thingy 
    }
performMagic("hello")
```

&

```
var newMagicFunction ={
  (thingy : String) -> String in 
return thingy
}
```

&

```
var addeFunction : (Int , Int) -> Int ={
  (a : Int , b : Int) -> Int in 
return a + b
} 
addeFunction(1,3)
```

Thanks

Comment: which part of the last one dont you understand exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only real difference between the last one and the 2nd last one, is that the type of the var is being declared in the last one, and the type of the var is inferred from what is being assigned to it in the 2nd one. (besides the obvious functionality difference) eg, you could swap them around sort of

```
var newMagicFunction : String -> String = {
  (thingy : String) -> String in 
  return thingy
}


var addeFunction = {
  (a : Int , b : Int) -> Int in 
  return a + b
} 
addeFunction(1,3)
```

which are equivalent to the above ones you posted

Comment: then in the last one , what is the role of this part " : (Int , Int) -> Int " because as u said and i just tried its existence or absence wouldn't make any change in the value it returns ????????    :)

Comment: its like going `var something:Int = 0` its the same as just going `var something = 0` the return value type is what comes after the `->` which is already in the closures parameter list which is what is before the `in`